# need help regex optional

Tags: python, regex

the code below works fine if the username is existed but what if there is "-" instead (no username)

```
(?P<host>\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}) - (?P<user_name>\w*) \[(?P<time>.*?)\] \"(?P<request>.*?)\"
```

username exists:

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
```

no username:

```
159.253.153.40 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:10 -0700] "POST /e-business HTTP/1.0" 504 19845
```

Comment: Enclose the optional part with an optional non-capturing group, `part` => `(?:part)?`.

Comment: This is not an optional field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field isn't optional, it's always there. But sometimes it contains a username, other times it contains `-`. So just use alternatives with `|` in the regexp to match either of them.

Also, `\w*` will allow a completely empty username, which is probably not allowed. Use `\w+` to match a non-empty field.

```
(?P<host>\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}) - (?P<user_name>\w+|-) \[(?P<time>.*?)\] \"(?P<request>.*?)\"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing your RegEx to match the `-` case as well, like this:

```
(?P<host>\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}) - (?P<user_name>\w*|-) \[(?P<time>.*?)\] \"(?P<request>.*?)\"
```

I used [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) to try your RegEx out.